# HTML5 <video> with text overlay executes onMouseOut load() function near the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I'm having trouble with an HTML5 video. Look it is a video that when you hover in it has to show a semi transparent overlay including text. When the mouse goes out, it has to show again the poster. The poster is an attribute that shows a thumbnail of the video when is not played yet.

In order to show the poster, I have searched other Stack Overflow questions and the workaround is to do: `video.load();`.

So I have the next piece of code:

### HTML:

```
<div class="video-container" onMouseOver="video.play();showOverlay('#video-overlay');" onMouseOut="video.load();hideOverlay('#video-overlay');">
  <video poster="https://example.com/poster.jpg" src="https://example.com/video.mp4" id="video" width="300" muted="muted" loop title="Example video" />
  <a href="#">
    <div class="overlay" id="video-overlay">
      <h5>Overlay Title</h5>
      <p>Overlay Description</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    z-index: 999; /* does not work */
}

.overlay > h5 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

### JS:

```
function showOverlay(selector){
  const overlay = document.querySelector(selector);
  overlay.style.opacity = "1";
}
function hideOverlay(selector){
  const overlay = document.querySelector(selector);
  overlay.style.opacity = "0";
}
```

### [WATCH THE DEMO](https://victorfornieles.com/films/)

The problem:

Well, when you hover the video and you are near the text (h5 or p tags) the video loads again. It should not restart, instead, continue as normal.

Tip: I have replaced `video.load();` for `video.pause();` and everything works fine. But that is not the functionality I want.

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: @WillJenkins sorry I forgot, now I have edited the question with the problem, but basically is when you hover the video and you are near the text (h5 or p tags) the video loads again. It should not restart, instead, continue as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ok, here is the edit:**

I think your problem is due to the difference in behavior between mouseover/mouseout events and mouseeenter/mouseleave events.

replacing the events in your code, should give you the desired behavior

```
<div class="video-container" onMouseEnter="video.play();showOverlay('#video-overlay');" onMouseLeave="video.load();hideOverlay('#video-overlay');">
```

info and examples on the behavior of these events and differences:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

Comment: I have tried it but seems to work only when the mouse enters, so when you are near the text, the overlay disapears...

Comment: i just changed the onmouseout to onmouseleave on your page and it works as you want it to

Comment: Please add some code in your answer. While links are helpful, sometimes they get broken and answer does not benefit anyone in the long run

Comment: @mnzbono that is correct! It works! Add this comment as an answer and I will mark as selected

Comment: i edited the original answer with this as suggested